# FB share in new window

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

I've got FB share working with the following code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fshare.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fferalmotion.com%2Fshare%3Fwatch%3Dfd5f0c2"> 
<img src="/images/logo/facebook.png" alt="share on facebook"/> 
</a>
```

The problem is it opens in a full browser window.  Does anybody know how I would get the share to open in the standard 500 x 360 pop-up window ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

javascript will do the job.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function myPopup(url) {
window.open( url, "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 500, width = 360, resizable = 0" )
}
//-->
</script>

<a target="_blank" href="javascript:myPopup('http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fshare.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fferalmotion.com%2Fshare%3Fwatch%3Dfd5f0c2')"> 
<img src="/images/logo/facebook.png" alt="share on facebook"/> 
</a>
```

Comment: A slightly better way to do this would be:
<a href="http://facebook.com/blah" onclick="window.opn(this.href,xxxx)"><img></a>

You should never put JS in the HREF (separation of content/behaviour, etc).

Comment: works but the pop up opens in the top left corner. how do you move it to the center of the window?

Answer (score 16):

use

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fshare.php%3Fu%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fferalmotion.com%2Fshare%3Fwatch%3Dfd5f0c2', '_blank', 'width=400,height=500');void(0);">
<img src="/images/logo/facebook.png" alt="share on facebook"/>
</a>
```